# How can I set the "activateAccountSuccessPath" for users with Control Panel access?

Tags: users, config, activation

I have a site that allows public registration, and I want to be able to control where users are redirected to after activating their account. However the default user group has access to the Control Panel, so as explained in “[activateAccountSuccessPath doesn't work as expected](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/4106/9)”, users are taken to the Control Panel login page after activation, rather than the path defined by the `activateAccountSuccessPath` config setting.

Is there any way to change that behavior, so even users with access to the Control Panel will get redirected to the `activateAccountSuccessPath` after account activation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a [plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction) that listens to the [users.onActivateUser event](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onActivateUser), and manually redirects the browser to your desired page.

Just add this code to your plugin’s primary class:

```php
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('users.activateUser', array($this, 'onActivateUser'));
}

public function onActivateUser(Event $event)
{
    /* @var UserModel $user */
    $user = $event->params['user'];

    // Are they in the default group?
    // (Indicates this was probably public registration)
    if ($user->isInGroup('myDefaultGroup'))
    {
        // Redirect them to the activateAccountSuccessPath
        $activateAccountSuccessPath = craft()->config->getLocalized('activateAccountSuccessPath');
        $url = UrlHelper::getSiteUrl($activateAccountSuccessPath);
        craft()->request->redirect($url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great stuff Brandon, this is working well. Just a couple of additional questions: **1.** is there anyway to get this working in conjunction with `autoLoginAfterAccountActivation` (I'm talking of a dashboard page which uses `{% requireLogin %}`). **2.** Is there any technical or security reason why this isn't built in as a default config setting?

Comment: @Rob This should work with autoLoginAfterAccountActivation = true. This isn’t something we would make a config setting because it’s super edge case. The expected behavior is that a user with access to the Control Panel would be directed to the Control Panel when their account has been activated.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with that setting and just redirects to `loginPath` — it's far better than our previous solution however, and (I've [updated my post with a full config setup](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13207/postcploginredirect-wrong-redirect-when-used-with-autologinafteraccountactivatio) for posterity)